# Cannot run in Visual Studio but works in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio

I have a project that runs fine in Visual Studio Code, but won't run in Visual Studio 2017.  When I run the project, I get a console window that pops up briefly reading:

> unhandled exception: system.io.filenotfound exception:  Could not load
>   file or assembly 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions,
>   Version=2.0.2.0....' or one of its dependencies.  The system cannot
>   find the file specified.  Main(String[] args)

The following is in the output window:

> The program '[18664] project.dll' has exited with code -532462766
>   (0xe0434352). The program '[18664] project.dll: Program Trace' has
>   exited with code 0 (0x0).

The program runs fine in Visual Studio Code.

My solution consists of two projects:

My startup project is has the following SDK dependencies:
 - .NETCoreApp2.0
 - .NETStandard2.0

My secondary project targets NETStandard.Libary v1.6.1

Comment: What version of Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions do you have?

Comment: Hi @kowieleroux.  I think that's the problem.  That said, I've abandoned the Visual Studio route.  VS Code was using a local binary version of the framework whereas VS requires that the SDK be installed.  I believe this is the issue, but have not tested it.